# Convert to .P12 Certificate

Tags: certificate

I have the following files

`server.csr`
`serverprivate.key`
`serverpublic.key`

Provided by vendor: `vendor.pem`

I need to convert the certificate to a .p12 files and tried the following command via `openssl`

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out esim.p12 -inkey private.key -in ca-preprod.crt`

and i'm getting "NO CERTIFICATE MATCHES PRIVATE KEY"

How to generate a `.p12` file using the files I have now?

Comment: The files you say you have are different from the filenames you give you `openssl`. What are the real file names and what does each correspond to?